# How to make REST API secure

Tags: java, spring, rest, security

I have an endpoint which posts data to the  API as below.

http://example.com/enablePushnotification?id=5609enable=true

The above API stores the value in the database, so now push notification is enabled for the user 5609.  How can I secure the API? A hacker/ troublemaker can simply change the id and in a for loop and then disable notification for all my customer base.

Is there a way I can make sure that the request made is authentic?

Comment: Add authentication to the API

Answer (score 0):

You should use Spring Security project.

There are several ways how to secure your API:

- simplest: [using basic authentication](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication),
- modern: [using JWT](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt).